# cURL vs wp_remote_get: which one is most reliable for external API call in Plugin?

Tags: wordpress, php-curl

I see, entire Internet filled with recommendations of using `wp_remote_get`  but there is no concrete reason except one line, this is right/wp way. Why?

Can someone highlights any tangible benefits of its over cURL? I am looking for reliable way that work in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: the reason why people normally recommend using [wp_remote_get()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/) over cURL, and I'm going to quote the official documentation here, is:

> ... to consistently make outgoing HTTP requests easy for developers
> while still being compatible with the many PHP configurations under
> which WordPress runs.

Source: [WP_Http](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http/)

(The [wp_remote_get()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/) function returns an instance of the WP_Http class, hence why I quoted the text from that page.)

For example, if cURL is not available on the server (or can't be used for some reason), the WP_Http class will fallback to using [PHP streams](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) instead (see [relevant code](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.6/wp-includes/class-http.php#L507-L548)). This removes the need for you, as a developer, to have to put checks in your code validating whether cURL is available or not.

You can use cURL though, that's a perfectly good option as well (in most cases at least.)